# Ignoring Parent Div Width

Tags: html, css

So I have an image (or a div that will contain the image) that I would like to use as a banner for portfolio.

[image: preview]

I would like this image to be the full width of the page (not height). However, this image is nested inside a div that contains all the information for each of my portfolio projects, and will not allow me to stretch outside of the container.

However, the current state of how I set margins and containers within my portfolio is a little messy, so examples online have been hard to follow.

The following are nested in the following order:

The ID that contains all of the projects

```
#contentContainer2 {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-bottom: 6em;
}
```

The ID that pushes the content/sets spacing:

```
#marginSetter2 {
   width: 63em;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: auto;
   padding: 0;
}
```

The ID that contains the individual project (and where the div that I want to extend to full width lives):

```
#projectDescription1 {
   padding-top: 1em;
}
```

If you would like to take a closer look at the code, please DM me and I will be happy to send you the link to the live version of my portfolio.

I apologize if stuff is a little messy; I started to build this portfolio when I was first starting to get out of my comfort zone with html/css/javascript, so I was not as experienced, and haven't gotten around to making large scale fixes.

Cheers,
Alejandro

Comment: Your css seems working. When you set a fixed width to the child element, it will never pick the parent width. Can you update the question with your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by using position-absolute. However, from a design standpoint, I would consider refactoring your containers a bit. Consider wrapping your container with margins in a new div along with this image instead of trying to shoehorn the image into a container it doesn't belong in.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Actual banner image */
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
```

Comment: This worked but now it has become really difficult to deal with adding bottom padding to the image because its position is absolute. I found a quick workaround by just adding a class that gives padding-top to the element below the banner, but that padding isn't actually pushing from the image, just the other element above it, so it is causing issues for responsiveness whenever the user increases the height of the browser window. I am so close to figuring this out any help is appreciated!